# How to delay within async function that returns Deferred<T>

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines, kotlin-coroutines

I have below kotlin coroutine code. `doWorkAsync` is normal (non suspend) function and it returns `Deferred<Int>`.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val result = doWorkAsync("Hello ")
}

fun doWorkAsync(msg: String): Deferred<Int>  = async {
    log("$msg - Working")
    delay(500)
    log("$msg - Work Done")
    return@async 42
}

fun log(msg: String ) {
    println("$msg in ${ Thread.currentThread().name }")
}
```

I don't know how to use `delay` within `doWorkAsync` function.

I'm using kotlin coroutines version `kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a scope:

```
fun doWorkAsync(msg: String) = GlobalScope.async {
    log("$msg - Working")
    delay(500)
    log("$msg - Work Done")
    return@async 42
}
```

This way, inside your lambda, you will have a `CoroutineScope`.

Note: Since you are using an expression body, you don't need to specify the return type `Deferred<Int>` explicitely. It can be inferred.

---

**A more flexible solution using a suspended function**

But there is an even better way. I mean in this context it is obvious that the function should be async. But what if you want a function that can be called asynchronous and sequentially?

That's where suspending functions come into play. You define your function like this:

```
suspend fun doWork(): Int {
    // ...
    delay(500)
    // ...
    return 42
}
```

An then you can decide at call-site how you want to use it:

```
val d: Deferred<Int> = GlobalScope.async { doWork() } // asnyc
val i: Int = runBlocking { doWork() } // sequential
```